# How to access HTML table using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, html-table, selenium-chromedriver, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to access html using selenium c# web driver.

Part of my html as follows ([Full html  is here](https://pastebin.com/em9CjTRC) ).

```
<table scope="band" type="tabular" cellpadding="2" border="0" bgcolor="#555555" id="bandstyle-Ver2" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
  <tr bandheader="true" type="table-header" height="22px">
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="2%" class="textbrownNew">No</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">Inst Catg</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="5%" class="textbrownNew">Inst - Branch</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">CF Type</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">CF Stat</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">Own - Shp</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">Crcy</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="7.5%" class="textbrownNew">Amount Granted / Limit</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="7.5%" class="textbrownNew">Current Balance</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="7.5%" class="textbrownNew">Arrears Amount</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="7.5%" class="textbrownNew">Installment Amount</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="7.5%" class="textbrownNew">Amount Written Off</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="6%" class="textbrownNew">Reported Date</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="6%" class="textbrownNew">First Disburse Date</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="6%" class="textbrownNew">Latest Payment Date</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="6%" class="textbrownNew">Restruct Date</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="6%" class="textbrownNew"> End  Date </td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="3%" class="textbrownNew">Repay Type</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="4%" class="textbrownNew">Purp.</td>
     <td label-type="text" height="1%" width="4%" class="textbrownNew">Coverage</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="22px">
     <td height="1%" width="2%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">1</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">CBC</td>
     <td height="1%" width="5%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">OWN-072</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">LOAN</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">ACTV</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">OWN</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">LKR</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">4,000,000</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">3,731,292</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">0</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">94,290</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">30-Jun-2018</td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">14-Feb-2018</td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">MNLY</td>
     <td height="1%" width="4%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">01:001</td>
     <td height="1%" width="4%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">FS &amp; OG</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="22px">
     <td height="1%" width="2%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">2</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">CBC</td>
     <td height="1%" width="5%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">CRCD</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">ACTV</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">OWN</td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">LKR</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">800,000</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">0</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">0</td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="7.5%" align="right" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">31-Jul-2018</td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">25-Apr-2018</td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="6%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="./CRIB Report Number _ W-0043111705_2018_files/spacer.gif"></td>
     <td height="1%" width="3%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">DMND</td>
     <td height="1%" width="4%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">03:001</td>
     <td height="1%" width="4%" class="text2New" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">US &amp; NG</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In my html there have multiple inner tables. [full html code](https://pastebin.com/em9CjTRC) To access this html file, I used following Selenium code.

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("reportcontainerstyle-Ver2"));
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

//To get days arrears details
var mainTable = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ConsumerCreditDetails_Version3"));
var subTables = mainTable.FindElements(By.Id("bandstyle-Ver2"));

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)//Skip header
    {
        var row = rows[i];
        var rowTds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

        if ((rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("LOAN") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("LEAS") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("CRCD") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("OVDR")) && rowTds[4].Text.Trim().Equals("ACTV") && rowTds[5].Text.Trim().Equals("OWN"))
        //if(true)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

In the HTML file, there have tables with id = `bandstyle-Ver2` I need to access 2nd table's data. To achive that I used above selenium code. But when I accessing table like that code. this error is occured.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

can anyone please tell me how to access those data.

**Updated: according to @sers answer I used following code:**

```
    var rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[.//td[normalize-space(.)='Credit Facility (CF) Details']][1]/following-sibling::table[1]//tr[not(@type='table-header')]"));

    foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
    {
        var cfType = row.FindElement(By.XPath("td[4]")).Text.Trim();
        var cfStat = row.FindElement(By.XPath("td[5]")).Text.Trim();

        if ((cfType.Equals("LOAN") || cfType.Equals("LEAS") || cfType.Equals("CRCD") || cfType.Equals("OVDR")) && cfStat.Equals("ACTV") && cfStat.Equals("OWN"))
        {

        }
    }
```

Then I also have a problem. I need to access these tables. this is that [HTML part](https://pastebin.com/d0WeVcGj) In this table I need to get the largest number of each table and if that number > 90 there have logic. to achieve that I used following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)//Skip header
    {
        var row = rows[i];
        var rowTds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

        if ((rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("LOAN") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("LEAS") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("CRCD") || rowTds[3].Text.Trim().Equals("OVDR")) && rowTds[4].Text.Trim().Equals("ACTV") && rowTds[5].Text.Trim().Equals("OWN"))
        {
            for (int subTab = 0; subTab < subTables.Count; subTab++)
            {
                if (subTab > 1)
                {
                    var colsDaysArrers = subTables[subTab].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
                    if (colsDaysArrers.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (colsDaysArrers[0].Text.Equals(crib.NO.ToString()))
                        {
                            for (int j = 1; j <= colsDaysArrers.Count - 1; j++)
                            {

                                var text = colsDaysArrers[j].Text;
                                if (!(text.Equals("--") || text.Equals("OK") || text.Equals("")))
                                {
                                    var val = double.Parse(text);
                                    if (val > 90)
                                    {
                                        crib.FACILITYARREARSSTATUS = "Irrigular";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        crib.FACILITYARREARSSTATUS = "Regular";
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Please tell me is this code is fine to do this? or have any otherway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First "Credit Facility (CF) Details" table:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//table[.//td[normalize-space(.)='Credit Facility (CF) Details']][1]/following-sibling::table[1]"));
```

Second "Credit Facility (CF) Details" table:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//table[.//td[normalize-space(.)='Credit Facility (CF) Details']][2]/following-sibling::table[1]"));
```

"Details of Settled Credit Facilities (Last 5 Years)" table:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[normalize-space(.)='Details of Settled Credit Facilities (Last 5 Years)' and @class='tblHeader']/ancestor::table[1]"));
```

"Summary of Potential and Current Liabilities (Excluding Settlements)" table:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//td[normalize-space(.)='Summary of Potential and Current Liabilities (Excluding Settlements)' and @class='tblHeader']/ancestor::table[2]//table[2]"));
```

Get all rows except header of first "Credit Facility (CF) Details" table:

```
var rows = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//table[.//td[normalize-space(.)='Credit Facility (CF) Details']][1]/following-sibling::table[1]//tr[not(@type='table-header')]"));

foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
    var cfType = row.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//td[4]")).Text.Trim();
    var cfStat = row.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//td[5]")).Text.Trim();

    if ((cfType.Equals("LOAN") || cfType.Equals("LEAS") || cfType.Equals("CRCD") || cfType.Equals("OVDR")) && cfStat.Equals("ACTV") && cfStat.Equals("OWN"))
    {
        foreach (IWebElement colsDaysArrers in driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//tr[./td[@class='textbrownNew' and @counter='true']]/td[not(@counter='true')]")))
        {
            var text = colsDaysArrers.Text;
            if (!(text.Equals("--") || text.Equals("OK") || text.Equals("")))
            {
                if (double.Parse(text) > 90)
                {
                    crib.FACILITYARREARSSTATUS = "Irrigular";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    crib.FACILITYARREARSSTATUS = "Regular";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I need to apply this

Comment: Please check my full html file too. hope that will be helped to you to help to me

Comment: I'm using C# sir,  I used `IWebElement` instead if `WebElement ` can you please tell me what is the **i** ? and there is no `get` method.

Comment: There were several mistakes I did, check it now

Comment: I really appreciate your help sir, please check my updated question. I used above code to change your answer. and I also need to get a largest no from next tables as I mentioned in my updated question part. Is this ok sir? or please give me an answer

Comment: This I previously tested code to access both parts. https://pastebin.com/rc1ENG4v I means your previous answer & my 2nd problem . after your answer how I need to do my 2nd part to get days more than 90?.

Comment: Check my last update you have to use updated part xpath var cfType = row.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//td[4]")).Text.Trim(); var cfStat = row.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//td[5]")).Text.Trim();. Do you have problem in my code?

Comment: Its now okay sir, Thank you very much :) I have another problem now. please check my updated question . I need to check each days and if any day have more than 90 , `crib.FACILITYARREARSSTATUS = "Irrigular";` how to get that

Comment: Ask developers to assign id's or modify html, because it's not testable.

Comment: I need to access this table too . https://pastebin.com/6gCRV0Tw how can I do it.please help me sir.

Comment: and there have another problem to me, when I check this tables, https://pastebin.com/d0WeVcGj for check days more than > 90 I also need to get **largset number of the tables ** how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Xpath -
(//*[@id='bandstyle-Ver2'])[2]//tr

here number 2 is table number you can have 1 ,3,4 depending upon your requirement.

(//*[@id='bandstyle-Ver2'])[2]//tr[1]/td[1]

above xpath will give you td of first row of your second table.

Now you can write a logic to make it generic .

Comment if you need more explanation

Comment: If you can please check my complete HTML and please give me a complete answer sir, because I'm really stacked on this :(